# AngularJs loading time optimization

Tags: angularjs, nginx

I have an AngularJS webapp. I´m trying to optimise the loading time and trying to understand where the app takes time. Everything looks pretty good until I get to this point in boat-rental.html [image]

I would like to know why that gap. It takes more than 1 second. I guess this is the time that AngularJs takes to load the whole framework and process the URL to get the right template. Is this right? Is there anyway to optimise this?

**UPDATE:** For testing purposes, I have minified the code in app.js and controllers, but nothing happened. My guess is that Angular is taking from 1 to 2 seconds to load the framework and process the url, which looks not very nice. Anyway to improve this performance?

Comment: Can you provide code that's in the  boat-rental.html? That would better help understand your problem so people can help you.

Comment: In order to escalate this issue we would require more info on the project architecture and things that you are using with your application like router (ngRoute or ui-router).

Comment: Can you please 'right click' on the network headers and add the 'time' table.